# Need a way to update DataGridView after editing the database externally

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a program that displays the contents of an Access table in a DataGridView.

I have the database imported into the solution with the necessary binding source, table adapters, etc. It shows the database contents in the DataGridView just fine.

I need to update this database using ANOTHER program. Is there any way I can auto-update the DataGridview with the new values when I change the data in the database by using, lets say, MS Access editor?

The event handlers from the BindingSource don't seem to trigger when I edit the database externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to keep updated with your excel file and then on `Change` event you could do what you want. It'll however work only when updating rows - changing schema (columns, names etc.) will won't work since your `databindingsource` is constant.